# HTML, how to check if a DIV is seen (not overflowed)?

Tags: html, css

How can I check if a DIV is visible? In other words, the DIV is inside its container?

[image]

In this picture, the active button (darkened) is visible because it is in the container:

But here:

[image]

The active button is not visible because its container has `overflow: hidden` and the button is outside the container. I want to remove buttons starting with 1, until the active button is visible in the container, but I simply have no idea how to check if the active div is visible or not

Comment: You might have to manually check the distance from the left side of the parent container for each child and see if it is greater than the parent width.

Comment: Post code, not just pictures.

Comment: This function seems to be what you are looking for -> **http://useallfive.com/thoughts/javascript-tool-detect-if-a-dom-element-is-truly-visible/**

Comment: mightbe, but it sends FALSE for everything....

Answer (score 1):

From what you wrote, it seems that you want to ensure that the active button is allways visible.

To achieve this effect, you do not have to remove buttons, you can adjust the .scrollLeft property of the parent container with reference to the left offset of the active button so that the active button is allways in view.